# Remove leading zeros from month with String.format in Java

Tags: java

How can I extract the month of a date object as a number without leading zeros using `String.format`?

Here is example code:

```
String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date())
```

If the month is February, this expression will produce the string "02", but I need to produce "2".

I must use `String.format`. I cannot use methods from other classes such as `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Parse it to Integer format :)

Comment: To clarify, I want a String object.  By "extract the month of a date object as a number" I just meant that I don't want something like "Feb" or "February".  Also, I cannot call any follow up methods.  I can only manipulate the format String.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Simple Date format is more better

```
package Test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateFromat {


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("M").format(new java.util.Date()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do some logic on the string like check if the first char is a "0" and then substring the rest or you could make it really easy and just use the Integer class and parse the string to an int like the following.

```
String format = String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date());
int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(format);
System.out.println(parseInt);
format = parseInt + "";
System.out.println(format);
```

or if you'd prefer a one liner

```
format = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date())));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(format));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct way to do this is to use regular expression to get the `2` without converting it to a number which may be a additional step.

Extracting from [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

`Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 13.`

So it's safe to follow the below approach

```
String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date()).replaceAll("^0", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
 System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date())));
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to format a date is to use java.text.SimpleDateFormat class. You can format the date that way much easier and does not require additional parsing or use of regex in my opinion:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("M").format(new java.util.Date()));
```

Will print "2" in case the current month is "February".

EDIT:

As SimpleDateFormat or other methods are not an option, I'd suggest using regex:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%tm", new java.util.Date()).replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
```

Comment: the question explicitly says SimpleDateFormat cannot be used, so this is not a good answer

Comment: oh, my bad. I am used to what I am used to... then I'd use regex ;)

Comment: that's fine.  but you should update your answer or delete it.